# Using ReadFields() function, retrieve n-th field value

Tags: vb.net, parsing, textfieldparser

I am currently reading a text file that has a fixed width.  Instead of looping, **is there a way to get let's say the fifth value** (which is one character if you look at the fixedWidths)?

Here is a copy of my code:

```
Private Function processPaymentRow(currentLine As String)
  Dim result As String()

  Using strStream As New StringReader(currentLine)
    Using MyReader As New TextFieldParser(strStream)
      MyReader.TextFieldType = FieldType.FixedWidth
      'Set proper field widths for the payment row here
      MyReader.FieldWidths = {10, 1, 10, 8, 1, 20, 13, 1, 8, 8, 8, 40,
                              40, 40, 40, 40, 25, 2, 9, 40, 10, 20, 6}
      Try
        result = MyReader.ReadFields()
        'Dim currentField As String
      Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
        MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped.")
      End Try
    End Using
  End Using
  For Each itm In result
    MsgBox(itm & " Pay")
    '// I can loop through the results and get the value I want.
  Next
  Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to loop any way if there is more than one line in the file? If there is only one line just read as text and use substring(4,1) to read the 5th character.

Comment: I am only reading in one line at a time.  If I was reading the entire file, then it would make more sense for me to loop through and get the values I want.  I have a system generating a text file and it has a lot of useless data in it.  I just need to extract the values I need, which is why I wanted to just get the position, instead of looping.  Thanks though.

Comment: If you are only dealing with one fixed width record at a time why not just use currentLine.substring(4,1)?

Comment: There are two different sections that have different fixed widths and different fields in the file.  Payment which is displayed and distribution which isn't displayed.  If it was all the same data throughout, using the substring(4, 1) would be a great solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` is a String array, so you should be able to grab `result(4)`, and that should give you your 5th value.

Comment: It works.  I think I tried it before but didn't run it because it said there was a potential for a null value... but after looking at my code, it wouldn't get to that point if there was a null value.  Thank you.